# Changing City, State, Zip Formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am learning Excel formulas and this place has been amazing.

I have 4 city, state, zip formats I am trying to make uniform. I do not have the source of the city, state, and zip so I can't run a simple formula to combine via concatenating.

I want all of them to be **City, State Zip -- five digits**

**Four Formats I am trying to manipulate:**

Richmond, VA 23230

Richmond, VA 23230-5595

Richmond, VA, 23230

Richmond, VA, 23230-5595

**What I have so far**

I am able to easily pull out the nine-digit zip codes using the below formula:

```
=IFERROR(+LEFT([@[Owner City State Zip2]],FIND("-",[@[Owner City State Zip2]])-1),[@[Owner City State Zip2]])
```

After running the above, I am now left with two city, state, zip formats:

1. Richmond, VA 23230
2. Richmond, VA, 23230

[image: Example]

Any suggestions for getting all of them formatted like number 1 where there is not an additional comma after the state abbreviation?

I can't use find and replace because the state is not always VA. My sheet could have 20 different states. And again, I don't have the source of the inputs so am not able to run a simple concatenation. I can use text to columns and concatenate but it doesn't seem efficient.

**Desired Result**

[image: Expected Result]

Thank you!

Comment: I can use text to columns, break them up into three columns and concatenate the three columns; however, it is a long process and I have a feeling there is a much more efficient way of running a single formula.

Comment: You question is not clear. What is your expected result? Can you please show on post?

Comment: Yes, added a picture. See how in rows 1 and 4 there was an additional comma after the state. I want those removed and all of them in City, State Zip.

Comment: Try my answer and le me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you given sample data it seems simple `SUBSTITUTE()` should work for you. Try-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","",2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun24HR. I am learning so much. I did not even know there was a substitute function. Thanks again.

Comment: @Exalted_X And if you have more than two comma in each cell then use this formula. `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[1]") & ", " & SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),",","")` this will keep 1 comma from left and will remove all the commas from right.

Comment: You're amazing. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Where column A is your data and column B is the formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;FIND(",";A1;1)+3);IF(ISERROR(FIND(",";RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1;1)-1);1));MID(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1;1)-1);3;6);MID(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1;1)-1);4;6)))
```

If you're using an older version of Excel, replace `;` with a comma

Comment: , and ; is not **old** version of excel - it is down to the system settings for language etc.